# How to make gcc ignore functions never called?

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(){
  printf("123\n");
}

int main(){
  printf("hi\n");
}
```

It seems no matter how I compile it,`func` always exists in the binary target?

Comment: What's the problem that you are trying to solve? The obvious solution is to delete the definition `func` from your source code but that seems to obvious.

Comment: What do you mean by "no matter how"? Could we have more specifics of what you've tried? Have you tried mad optimization?

Answer (score 6):

Functions have extern linkage by default in C. Making it `static` should inform the linker it's not needed outside and it should leave it out.

Comment: static per se does not allow gcc to perform dead code removal. See answer below

Answer (score 2):

You already tried -fwhole-program? (The compiler doesnt know before linking which functions he really later uses, this tells him, that there is nothing else, also the -lto (and related) could work)

Answer (score 2):

`func()` must be retained in the object code generated from your source file because it has external linkage so it might be used from another object file that you choose to link against.

E.g., one containing:

```
int x = (func(), 0);
```

It may be that the linker can detect that the function isn't actually used when you perform the final link. If the function had internal linkage (for example, if you added the `static` storage class specifier) then it would be possible for the compiler to detect that the function was not use and omit generating any object code for it.

The simplest 'fix' is just to remove the definition of `func` from your source file.

Answer (score 1):

Specific answer:
results on Solaris 10, RHEL 4:

```
gcc -funit-at-a-time  file.c  -o
```

with "static" declared func produces nm output of (edited, Solaris example):

```
[39]    |    133316|       0|OBJT |LOCL |0    |16     |force_to_data
[37]    |     67064|       0|FUNC |LOCL |0    |9      |frame_dummy
[78]    |     67208|      36|FUNC |GLOB |0    |9      |main
[44]    |    133360|      24|OBJT |LOCL |0    |22     |object.2
```

gcc file.c -o file  produces:

```
[39]    |    133356|       0|OBJT |LOCL |0    |16     |force_to_data
[37]    |     67064|       0|FUNC |LOCL |0    |9      |frame_dummy
[49]    |     67208|      32|FUNC |LOCL |0    |9      |func
[79]    |     67240|      36|FUNC |GLOB |0    |9      |main
[44]    |    133400|      24|OBJT |LOCL |0    |22     |object.2
[46]    |    133392|       0|OBJT |LOCL |0    |21     |p.0
```

And because gcc -O2  turns on -funit-at-a-time:

```
[54]    |    133308|       0|OBJT |LOCL |0    |16     |force_to_data
[37]    |     67064|       0|FUNC |LOCL |0    |9      |frame_dummy
[78]    |     67208|      24|FUNC |GLOB |0    |9      |main
[44]    |    133344|      24|OBJT |LOCL |0    |22     |object.2
```

since -O2 has other side effects, like rendering the debugger usage less reliable,
consider using

```
gcc -funit-at-a-time file.c -o file
```

Comment: Strange, but you have an "old" system, probably your gcc is also old, because my man page tells me for `-funit-at-a-time`: 
     This option is left for compatibility reasons. `-funit-at-a-time'
     has no effect,

Answer (score 0):

This is a common optimization called [dead code elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination), so probably GCC will perform it even at low optimization levels.

Comment: I dont think so. For two reason. DCE (at least the last time I digged into gcc) (and many other optimization passes too) work only on procedure basis, i.e. only dead code inside functions is removed, but not whole functions. Second reason that it cannot be removed, is that the compiler dont know before linkage, that it is actually dead code, as some other object file could reference it at link time. So you have either to say him that it is not external visible (by making it static) or by using some switches, that tell him that there is nothing else referencing the code (like -fwhole-program).

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile with `-ffunction-sections` `-fdata-sections`. These options should help to reduce executable size. [Reducing Executable Size](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Reducing_Executable_Size).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include/exclude some functions under some condition your can use preprocessor directives:

```
#if defined(MYCONDITION)
void func(){
  printf("123\n");
}
#endif
```