# C++ linker order issue - Linking my own main with a subset of object files in a large C++ project

Tags: c++, linker

I have a large C++ project with around 250 cpp files. 
I didn't write this code, I'm just trying to write a test for fuzzing(testing) purpose. Therefore:

- I wrote my own main cpp file, called wrapper.cpp, containing the int main()
- I included in this file some header files needed
- I compiled after removing the inital main from the Makefile and adding my wrapper.cpp

It works, it produces a functionnal executable. However, the binary size is quiet important. I'm pretty sure I can reduce the size as a lot of object files are linked but not used. Therefore, I built all the object files and now I'm thinking about how to link the needed ones with the executables. But after many tries, it seems impossible:

- The executable is linked against the object files, some static libraries and some dynamic lib
- The order matters for the static libs (interdependencies between them and some *.o files)
- There a several definitions for some symbols and this is allowed by the zmuldefs linker option

Thus, I first tried to create a bug static libs with all the object files and to link the executable against it assuming only the right .o files would be picked by the linker. I didn't think about the order problem ... Some of these object files need symbols contained in other static lib and vice versa (interdependencies). No matter where I place the static lib I created, there will be issues. So I can't go this way, it is too complex. 
Then, I tried to add the -Wl,--start-group/-Wl,--end-group linker option. It allows my to compile but the binary will segfault. I guess this is because of the zmuldefs option that allows multiple definitons, so the order is really important.

So I was wondering if there was a way to this, maybe an obvious way that I'm missing ?  Cause it seems to be a pretty common use case to me(imagine if you want to test a single function), but I cannot cannot find anything online.

Thank you in advance for your precious help

Comment: Are you familiar with mock/stub code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, but here it wouldn't be relevant. I'm trying to do fuzz a function, which means I need all the code paths of this function.

Comment: but it was linkable before your change right? maybe you just need to add an ifdef to the original 'main' and leave the rest as is?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444405/how-to-make-gcc-ignore-functions-never-called help?

Comment: Yes, the -Wl,--gc-sections option did the trick ! Thank you !